# How to place labels to the right in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I would like to know, how I could place the labels to the right in Bootstrap 5 and correctly place the button at the same alignment as the inputs, please?

I thank you in advance for your explanations.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
   </head>
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <body>
      <div class="container pt-5 text-center">
         <h1 class="pb-5">Title</h1>
         <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
               <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label" style="min-width: 240px !important">Portfolio holder</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 70%" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
               <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label" style="min-width: 240px !important">Country</label>
                  <select class="form-select">
                     <option>Belgium</option>
                     <option>France</option>
                     <option>Italy</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
               <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label" style=" min-width: 240px !important">Client file number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 70%" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
               <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
                  <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label" style="min-width: 240px !important">Type of account</label>
                  <select class="form-select">
                     <option >All agencies</option>
                     <option>ATH - Ath</option>
                     <option>BAU - Baudour</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Opening an account</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: we dont see your classes, atc, hard to advice, but as i know bootstraps, you shall use !important in your css/scss file after atribute, you want to execute, and ignore bootstrap class. Its not nice solution, but only one working for me when i have to work with bootstraps.

Comment: Bootstrap does have some good options for form layout but unvolves using their standard documentation and items such as `form-control`. Lots of answers right here >> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/

Comment: @Cute Code Rob; the problem i that I don't find what I want to do...

Comment: @Dima Malko: How can I align my labels to the right in bootstrap? I do not see?

Comment: You give your <div> position:relative, after that you give <label class="my-class" />. In css file you write .my-class { position: absolute !important, top: 0px !important, right: 0px !important}

Comment: Do you strictly want the label on the right and so the form inputs will be on the left? If so you should be able to simply swap their order in the HTML and put the labels after the inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go...

Add this to all your label classes: `d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end pe-3`

To explain you shortly:

- `d-flex` is essential in order for `justify-content-` and `align-items-` to work
- `justify-content-end` moves your labels to the right
- `align-items-end` moves your labels down so that they're aligned with forms
- `pe-3` sets padding-right

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>

  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-skAcpIdS7UcVUC05LJ9Dxay8AXcDYfBJqt1CJ85S/CFujBsIzCIv+l9liuYLaMQ/' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container pt-5 text-center">
    <h1 class="pb-5">Title</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end pe-3" style="min-width: 240px !important">Portfolio holder</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 70%" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end pe-3" style="min-width: 240px !important">Country</label>
          <select class="form-select">
            <option>Belgium</option>
            <option>France</option>
            <option>Italy</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end pe-3" style=" min-width: 240px !important">Client file number</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="exampleInputEmail1" style="width: 70%" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="d-inline-flex col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end pe-3" style="min-width: 240px !important">Type of account</label>
          <select class="form-select">
            <option>All agencies</option>
            <option>ATH - Ath</option>
            <option>BAU - Baudour</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Opening an account</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```